# AngularJS Extending Directive Return

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am really new to Angular... I have been trying to google on how to to do this but I think my lack of knowledge keeps me from wording my question correctly thus I am here.

Here is what I am trying to do with my code

```
ng.module('app.navigation', [
            ])
            .controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http, $filter){
                $scope.message = "Load in the navigation"; 
            }])
            .directive('navigation', function() {
                return {
                    templateUrl: 'navigation.view.html',
                    cssUrl: 'navigation.css',
                    link: $.NavbarSlide,
                };
            });
```

As you can see in my directive return I have put in a cssUrl... this obviously doesn't exist in Angular so what I am trying to do is figure out how to extend Angular with my own 3rd part extension so that I can do something with "cssUrl".

Comment: Why don't you just link to the external stylesheet from inside of `navigation.view.html`? That would be much less of a headache than trying to augment core Angular directives.

Comment: I just figured it would look cleaner because then I could tie that to a function that would then create an new link element and append it to the head tag much like requirejs but this would be like a requirecss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a cue from this project https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

```
ng.module('app.navigation', [
            ])
            .controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http, $filter){
                $scope.message = "Load in the navigation"; 
            }])
            .directive('navigation', function() {
                return CustomFunction({
                    templateUrl: 'navigation.view.html',
                    cssUrl: 'navigation.css',
                    link: $.NavbarSlide,
                });
            });
```

Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier.

Comment: Any chance you could add some extra explanation here? What does `CustomFunction()` do?